# How to turn off notification about available updates in Modern-UI apps?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-store-app, software-update

When I start any Windows 8.1 Modern-UI app, it may notify me that the app need update.

Thus, to use it I have to update the app, but this is troublesome if I don't want to update the app (at that time).

**For example**, the Modern-UI Video app shows "Your app needs an update. To keep using it, get the latest version at Windows Store."

Thus I must update it to use it.

How can I stop these in-app update notifications, and/or is there a way to disable them from *checking* for new versions?

**NOTE**: I have disabled auto-update of Windows Store apps via group policy and via the Store app.

I have also considered that it may be possible to reset to 0 the number of app updates available. For that I have tried setting the following registry key to 0, but without any success:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Store]
"PersistedUpdateCount"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: I don't have Win 8 in front of me right now, but does this help any?: To turn off Windows Store notifications without affecting notifications from any other app, open the Windows Store. Then, choose the “Settings” charm when on the Windows Store. From the Settings charm, click “Permissions”. Finally, under the “Notifications” section, where it says “Allow this app to show notifications”, slide the switch to “Off”. You can switch it back to “On” if you want to re-enable notifications.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Have already tried this... This disables the notifications that are shown on the desktop. So, this does not work :(

Comment: That's kind of what I figured. :/  Well you've got me intrigued. :)

Comment: Easy solution : don't waste your time with modern UI apps.